# ¿Cómo hago para que cuando mi nav responsive sea utilizado se cierre automaticamente?

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que pasa es que cuando intento hacerlo solo me toma solo el primer link sabiendo que todos los demás tienen las mismas clases, o sea que el primero de todos se cierra automáticamente después de ser usado pero los demás no y eso es lo que estoy intentando solucionar porque sería raro que un nav no se cerrase luego de cumplir ya con su función

Paso a adjuntar el codigo

HTML

```
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="nav">
            <div class="container-nav">
                <div class="container-logo">
                    <h2><span class="color">Leo</span>González<span class="color">.</span></h2>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav__list">
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#first-page" class="link">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="link">Sobre mi</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#proyects" class="link">Proyectos</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#contact" class="link">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="toggle">
                    |||
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #00000022;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.nav {
    background: var(--second-color);
}

.container-nav {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    line-height: 80px;
}

.container-logo {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container-logo h2 {
    color: var(--font-color);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.container-logo h2 .color {
    color: var(--first-color);
    font-weight: 700;
}

.nav__list .nav__item {
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav__list .nav__item .link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--font-color);
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav__list .nav__item .link:hover {
    color: rgba(28, 108, 173);
}

.toggle {
    color: var(--font-color);
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    display: none;
}

.rotate {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
/* Nav solo esto */
    .toggle {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .nav__list {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: #ddd;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: calc(100vh - 80px);
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 100000000;
        top: -100vh;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .active {
        top: 80px;
    }

    .nav__list .nav__item:hover {
        background: #aaa;
    }

/* Nav solo esto */

    .feed-form {
        width: 350px;
    }

    .first-page-name {
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .first-page-work {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

JS

```
const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
const links = document.querySelector(".nav__list");
const navItem = document.querySelector(".link")

toggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggle.classList.toggle("rotate")
    links.classList.toggle("active")
})

navItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggle.classList.toggle("rotate")
    links.classList.toggle("active")
})
```

Soy relativamente nuevo en esto y lo de JS fue pura lógica mía, quizá y esté muy mal pero según yo era lo que iba

Espero que me puedan ayudar y gracias jaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querySelector devuelve el 1 solo elemento (el primero) de los elementos que tengan la clase/id/tag que especifiques, para lo que quieres hacer tu selector debe devolver una coleccion HTML, podes hacerlo con getElementsByClassName, para después recorrer con un for-of y asignar el evento click a cada elemento:

```
const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
const links = document.querySelector(".nav__list");
const navItems = document.getElementsByClassName("link")

toggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggle.classList.toggle("rotate")
    links.classList.toggle("active")
})

for(const elem of navItems){
  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toggle.classList.toggle("rotate")
    links.classList.toggle("active")
  })
}
```

Otra alternativa es usar querySelectorAll